# Python Regex: Chain Multiple Substitutions In Function

Tags: python, regex

I am looking to clean URL's in the else block of an if. Specifically, strip the ? and all query parameters after it as well as everything before the first "/".

**Example Input** = 'somesite.com/somepage?param=1&else=2'

**Example Output** = 'somepage'

** All that is left is our page (no query params and no domain) **

Below is what I have so far (not working). I was focused on piecing this out and the below was an attempt on stripping all query parameters. I'm not sure how I would chain both together.

```
def new_url_check(x):
    
    if 'some condition' in x:
        x = 'some random condition'           
            
    else:
        re.sub(r'^([^?]+)', '', x)
            
    return x
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to *assign* to `x` or `return` the result of your `re.sub` call, and the regex should include some requirements that concern the forward slash. Also there is the `#` symbol that has a special meaning:

```
x = re.sub(r'^.*/|[?#].*', '', x)
```

If you want to keep the first part of the path instead of the last, then:

```
x = re.sub(r'^.*?/+.*?/|[/?#].*', '', x)
```

This assumes that the host is included in the input, and starts with at least a forward slash. So it will work for the following:

```
http://localhost/abc/def/ghi  => abc
/localhost/abc/def/ghi => abc
```

Comment: if I wanted to grab the first page in a nested directory (meaning there are multiple /), what would that look like? ex: /some_page/another_page/third_page and we only want "some_page" (the first instance). I believe your answer would provide the last, or "third_page" in the example.

Comment: Added a section to the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure the regex to grab the first path works, see an example:
print(re.sub(r'^.*?/+.*?/|[/?#].*', '', '/somepage/?param_1=62&param2=123'))

Comment: As I indicate in my answer, the host must be present in the URL for this to work, and must be preceded by a slash. If this is not so, then just exclude `.*?/` from the regex, because then there is one slash less to remove.

Answer (score 0):

howabout using re.search and setting what you want aside as a group?

```
re.search(r'.*\.com\/(.*)\?.*', x).group(1)
```